# php code not running properly under script tag

Tags: javascript, php

i have the following php code its running properly independently, but the problem is it runs on form load as well
so i kept it inside  tag

```
       <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    <?php
     $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
     $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     $extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo '<script>alert(" Logo with this name already exists.")</script>';
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo '<script>alert("project logo uploaded successfully")</script>';
  }
  }
  }
  else
  {
  echo '<script> alert("Invalid file")</script>';
       }
     ?>         
    });
    </script>
```

but the problem is this its executing uploading the the file but not generating alerts
please help!!

Comment: `;` missing after the `alert`

Comment: Yeah, its that simple. A look into the console would have shown you the problem ... JS statements need to be terminated with a `;`, just like PHP.

Comment: its still not working even after adding ;

Comment: Can you check the output of this in the browser and see what is happening?

Comment: @KraneBird its executing uploading file to the desired folder but my problem is why is it not giving alerts... when am simply writing it with just <?php ?> its running and generating alerts but when i kept it inside script tag and it stop giving alert

Comment: I meant: can you see the html output? and post it here?

Answer (score 2):

the output of your code;

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
 <script> alert("Invalid file")</script>
    });
    </script>
```

should be;

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Invalid file");
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `<script>` element inside another `<script>` element.
Run the generated HTML through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).